# Writing specific lines from one txt file to another using Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, text

Given a for loop, I want to write specific lines from one text file to another using Matlab. The solutions that I've seen mention putting the text file into an array/matrix and writing line by line and reading line by line (whereas I want to read specific lines) but they reformat the data (ex. adding ' ' to strings and [] to ints). Below is a vague idea of the code: textFile & otherTextFile = the files I want to write to, data = everything from that specific line of the txt file, i = line of the text file.

```
for i = 1:100
    if i < 15
        fprintf(textFile, data);
    else
        fprintf(otherTextFile, data);
    end
end
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Edit: I wasn't too clear, but my actual code needs it to write from several different specific sections, ex. lines 1-15, 60-70 copied to one file, the other lines to another file. Using the below accepted answer, you would just use that exact implementation and keep putting the fprintf statements between your if/elseif/else statements.

Comment: So, you want the first 14 lines of the source text file in one file, and the next 86 in the other file?

Comment: In my actual code, I'm trying to copy lines 1-15 and 66-90 to one file, and the others to a second file.

Comment: Modify your question with those conditions, and I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A text file is a stream of bytes, meaning that there's no explicit information stored in the text file saying "the line number *n* starts at **that** position". So, as soon as the file is open, first read line is first, second read line is second and so on.

Some code to illustrate:

```
% Some named numbers
N_LINES  = 100
N_SWITCH = 15

% Open files
fin   = fopen('inputfile.txt', 'r');
fout1 = fopen('outfile1.txt', 'w');
fout2 = fopen('outfile2.txt', 'w');

% Split lines between the 2 files
for i = 1:N_LINES
        % Read input
        data = fgets(fin);
        if feof(fin)
                break;
        end;

        % Write output
        if i < N_SWITCH
                fprintf(fout1, '%s', data);
        else
                fprintf(fout2, '%s', data);
        end;
end;

% Close files
fclose(fin);
fclose(fout1);
fclose(fout2);
```